# Is backbone.js (or any similar framework) useful for a single page in a multi-page application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I'm making a board game in rails, and was considering using backbone.js (or a competing library) to handle the gameplay page and manage all of the models and the UI. Is it useful for something like this (over just making my own classes)? Or is it really only worth it for making a single page app? I've read a bit about the library, but I can't tell if its features will help simplify what i'm trying to do or if they are just overkill for a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Backbone can handle this perfectly. 37signals, for example (founded by Rails's creator DHH) uses Backbone for the calendar, but not on the other pages.